# Adding a list item

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

Could anyone please help me sort out a bug in my beginner code? I am trying to add an list item to a list and trying to change the id of what list i'm adding it to in javascript. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    button.onclick = changeDiv;
}
function changeDiv() {
    var counter=1
    var name = "ul";
    var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
    var userInput = textInput.value;
    alert("adding " + userInput);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = userInput;
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul" + loop());
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

function loop() {
    return counter;
    if (counter==3){
        counter==0;
    }
    counter++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input id="textInput" type="text" placeholder="input text here">
        <input id="submit" type="button">
    </form>
    <ul id="ul1">
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul2">
    </ul>
    <ul id="ul3">
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: What happens instead? *Describe* the bug/behavior.

Comment: Your `loop()` function isn't right. What should it do?

Comment: i think you want 1) the scope of `counter` to be global (yuk) OR 2) create a closure around everything and declare `counter` there   OR  3) you could pass `counter` into `loop()` when you call it.  or 4) define `loop()` in `changeDiv()`.  I think you want #2 though

Comment: The loop is returning a value first, meaning that it halts execution and doesn't do anything else afterwards. Move the return statement to the end, and it will work better.

Comment: No need for the "I'm a noob"...

Answer (score 2):

i think you want is one of these:

1. Give the scope of `counter` to be global (yuk)
2. create a closure around everything and declare `counter` there
3. you could pass `counter` into `loop()` when you call it.
4. define `loop()` in `changeDiv()`.

I think you want #2 though so I fiddled it with several corrections in your code:

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjTAm/)

The reason that I went with #2 is:

- that a closure allows your logic to gain application to the resources it needs
- but protect the scope at which other applications might be running (now or in the future) from being affected by any changes your application might attempt to that scope.   For example, if you declared the counter as a global then all other javascript would potentially have read/write access to it which could negatively affect your demonstrated code, the other code, or both
- keeps your current beginner code as unchanged as possible
- gets you programming with an extremely important aspect of javascript that will help you today and in future as you learn

Answer #4 is similar in that it would create a closure for both changeDiv and loop whereby they both have access to what they need.  However, I didn't want to change your existing logical blocks too much to stall incremental learning.  But one could definitely make an argument for the `loop()` (which isn't really a loop but rather a setter) being enclosed in `changeDiv()` -- albeit you would likely remove the separate function call at that point and integrate the code more.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't realize that the variable had to be global.

Comment: @JamesDorfman i wouldn't make it global though, just "change it's scope", but still use a closure like I've fiddled for you so you don't run into trouble.  Globals (global pollution) should be avoided, especially with a name like `counter`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to:

- declare `counter` in a global scope (`loop()` cannot access it otherwise)
- in `loop()`, the return statement must be the LAST thing. Anything after it won't get executed.

I altered the logic a bit and the final code is this:

```
window.onload = init;
var counter=1;
function init(){
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    button.onclick = changeDiv;
}
function changeDiv(){
    var name = "ul";
    var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
    var userInput = textInput.value;
    var id = "ul" + loop();
    alert("adding " + userInput + " to " + id);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = userInput;
    var ul = document.getElementById(id);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

function loop(){
    var tmp = counter++;

    if (counter==4){
        counter=1;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Note the changes in the `loop()` function.

I also altered the `changeDiv()` function to display the list ID in the alert.

Comment: @Mörre you are correct; I was working on a better answer just as you wrote the comment. (EDIT: this was a reply to a comment that apparently got deleted).

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. It's people like you that allow me to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: @mingos in the interest of making folks use better practices I'll make two key comments here. While in this particular case you are correct that the `return` was not allowing any other code execution in `loop()` however it is not _syntactically_ true that the `return` needs to be the "last" thing since it could be conditional and other expressions might be listed "after" it.   Also a global declaration like this should be discouraged.

Comment: @gillyspy True and true. But bear in mind that the OP explicitly stated he was a beginner and I think the simplest solution was to just suggest the (architectonically undesired) global var. In your answer, you offered a solution that introduced a change (OK, improvement) in the program's architecture. This change was not requested. You failed to explain why you deemed this change necessary (and I believe such an explanation would be OT). As for the `return` statement, I meant it was to be the last thing *executed*, not *written*. I should have made it clearer.